# Shiny apps doesn't display properly on server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I tried to deploy my dashboard to shinyapps.io however, this particular dashboard cannot be deployed properly as it is in R studio. Below is its appearance in R studio (it also functions normally in R studio):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpWdL.png)

Here is its appearance in shinyapps.io:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaObU.png)

It should not be attributed to the version of my Rstudio or Shiny package as I can still deploy other dashboards normally. Everything looks fine during the deployment process. No warnings or errors.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Initially, it looks like it can't find the CSS file. What packages are you using to style your dashboard? If you share some code, it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: I found the solution: https://community.rstudio.com/t/ui-completely-different-under-local-and-shinyapps-io-when-using-highcharter/165998. I need to update the httpuv package to 1.6.11. The 1.6.10 is bugged. Thank you for taking the look!